# Adding Web service API to Michael Hartl's completed Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services

Thank you Michael Hartl, the tutorial is awesome!

Can anyone please advise of the next steps to expose some functionality in the form of a service API. in particular, I am interested in having an iPhone client and was wondering of the best way (most secure, fast, clean) to accomplish that. Is it advisable to introduce a token that would be passed with every service call? what I can add to the current authentication/session implementation to mirror this on the iPhone side? (i.e, carry a "forever" session, and secure API calls).

Thank you! any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I should add http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book